# HAT EEPROM address is said to be 0x50, but 0xA0 is most common when A0-A2 are tied low

Tags: hat, eeprom

CAT24C32 is a widely recommended HAT EEPROM. The data sheet says the 4 MSBs are 1010 or Ah. But 0x50 is widely stated to be the correct EEPROM address. Some who recommend the CAT24C32 also say the address bits should be 0x50. I have looked at microchip parts and they all have Ah MSBs.

What am I missing? CAT24C32 and 24LC256 specify Ah. Note that Ah (1010) is the complement of 5h (0101).

Comment: Check the data sheet from the manufacturer of the EEPROM.

Comment: Yes Gil, that is what i did Ah which seems to be the standard in the DATA SHEETS I looked at does not equal the widely mentioned 5h.

Comment: Sometimes there is confusion because  the 7-bit address is actually sent in the most significant  bits of the 8-bit  byte.  Some manufactures  give a value which is wrong  and  is  twice the value seen on the  bus.

Comment: Shift it right 1 and then look at the 7 least significant bits. When the address is sent the LSB is either a 0 or 1 depending on whether it is a write or read command. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Joan and Gil. Guess I'll use one of the standard EEPROMS and see how it works. It probably will work because I have never seen any reports of addressing problems.